# How can I create the ability for a user to create a playlist from stored tracks using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to think of a means of implementing a feature in which a user can in some way get a list of tracks from my track table, and then highlight what tracks they want to store into their playlist and create a playlist based on the tracks they submitted. I have to do this through PHP implementing MySQL statements inside it.

I already have the tables set up in MySQL, I just need suggestions and ideas on how I can lay this out on a php form.

**Tracks Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Tracks` (  
`Track_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
`Track_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
 `Length` time NOT NULL,  
 `Artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `Album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Track_id`), 
  KEY `Artist_id` (`Artist_id`),  
  KEY `Album_id` (`Album_id`), 
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tracks_ibfk_1` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Artist` (`Artist_id`),  
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tracks_ibfk_2` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Album_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Albums`  (`Album_id`))
```

**Playlists Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Playlists` (  
`Playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Playlists_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`User_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Playlist_id`,`User_id`),  
 KEY `User_id` (`User_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Playlists_ibfk_2` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Users` (`User_id`))
```

**Playlist Tracks Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Playlist_Tracks` (  
`P_Tracks_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
`Playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`Track_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`P_Tracks_id`),  
 KEY `Playlist_id` (`Playlist_id`),  
 KEY `Track_id` (`Track_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Playlist_Tracks_ibfk_1` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Playlist_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Playlists` (`Playlist_id`),         
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Playlist_Tracks_ibfk_2` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Track_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Tracks` (`Track_id`))
```

What I was suggested by a college, was using a radio button on the listed tracks for the user to click on and highlight, then they press a button to put that track into their corresponding playlist table. The only issue is I have NO idea on how I can go around setting up such a form in php and creating a SQL statement to work with these three tables.

Comment: How about you create a form and inside the form have a loop that for each track PHP will render a checkbox input where the user can click on and at the end of the form have an "ADD" button that will send the post request and create the relation in the database?

Comment: @Baruch Could you further elaborate? :) Like could I have some example code? Just to see how I'd start it

Comment: This is not really the forum for what is essentially a "How do I program?" question.  I would suggest going to http://www.w3schools.com/php/ and going through the tutorials.  By the end you should have a good understanding of how to complete this task.

Comment: I'm capable of programming in php, the only real issue id finding a place to start. Once I get started on a layout I can pretty much work from that